# Make the "corona" tag synonym of "coronasdk"

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request, synonym-request

"corona" and "coronasdk" both refer to [Corona SDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corona_%28software_development_kit%29) most of the time. Sometimes tag [corona](/questions/tagged/corona) refers to something else I didn't figure out what is. It seems a rarity, though.

Comment: So... noone will work on this? How it works now? How I know when a moderator will actually review this?

Comment: People with at least 2,500 karma and 5 answer karma on Corona need to upvote: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/corona/synonyms

Comment: Yes, someone explained that to me, this is why I wrote this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168536/low-visibility-tags-are-too-hard-to-moderate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, [corona](/questions/tagged/corona), and [coronasdk](/questions/tagged/coronasdk) have a tag excerpt, and a tag wiki that contain a description of (or a reference to) the Corona SDK. This means the purpose of both the tags is the same.

There are 164 questions that use [both the tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coronasdk+corona). The tags should be merged.

Comment: Thanks :)

Can I get a explanation of the difference between tag merge and tag synonym then? I mean, why use synonym?

Comment: A tag merge involves all the questions, past and future; a tag synonym involves only future questions. If [tag:corona] is made a synonym of [tag:coronasdk], future questions using [tag:corona] will see that tag replaced with [tag:coronasdk], but the tag is still shown in old questions. If [tag:corona] is merged with [tag:coronasdk], all the questions that use [tag:corona] will see it replaced with [tag:coronasdk].

Comment: Hey, can someone please merge those tags?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after nearly an year [coronasdk](/questions/tagged/coronasdk) has become a synonym of [corona](/questions/tagged/corona).

Though the count is different for both tags, I think it'll be fixed after next cache cycle runs (or something; since *it's always the caching*).

Comment: Nope, that's not how tag synonyms work. There are currently 590 questions tagged with [tag:coronasdk], and they will stay that way until they get retagged to the master tag or a moderator merges the two tags. ;)