# Low visibility tags are too hard to moderate

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, moderation

I am the fourth place in votes in the [Corona tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/corona/info) on Stack Overflow, yet my total score there is 32. The top score is 69.

Yet the tag is fairly active, mostly because Stack Overflow is better to get replies than the official forums (specially because some CoronaLabs staff patrol Stack Overflow to reply questions too), but several replies there end with 0 votes, and many are not accepted either.

Yet, there are some things that I want to do, like merge or make tags synonyms and so on. But there is no way to do it, because no one (not even the top scoring guy) has sufficient reputation points.

I can bet this is a pattern not only with Corona; any fairly popular tech will end with lots of questions on Stack Overflow, and some people will focus on that tag, but with newbies asking the questions and never accepting or upvoting, the regulars of those tags never get sufficient power to do anything meaningful on them.

Note: Last time I complained about this (in a badly written post here that got lots of downvotes) I was told to create a post here on Meta Stack Overflow. I did so, five months ago, it got upvoted, and some high-scoring person made a good reply that I accepted. See *[Make the “corona” tag synonym of “coronasdk”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146064/make-the-corona-tag-synonym-of-coronasdk)*.

Yet... The issue was not fixed. I asked on the [Freenode chat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freenode) why this happened, and then people told me that there is this requirement of score in the tag, thus nagging a C++ user (I, for example, nagged user *Lightness Races in Orbit*) don't help me.

How can we fix this?

Comment: Fully agreed. Top user on [tag:google-charts] has 54, next is 20. Top in [tag:google-visualization] is 58.

Comment: Related: [Can we allow 7.5K users  to suggest tag synonyms without a score of 5 in the tag?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/103211) (declined) and [Drop the score requirement for proposing tag synonyms (atleast for Super User)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/69588)

Answer (score 7):

It seems like the answer is to make the tag wiki editors a proportion to the scores; maybe the top X% of scorers in that tag can edit that tag wiki?

Comment: I like that! Specially applied to other sites (for example, the Game Development site on stackexchange has langauge and API tags usually with much higher score than non-programming tags)

Comment: As an alternative or replacement to the existing requirments?

Comment: @madth3 I see it as an alternative for tags that are 'niche' tags.  Ultimately I think that standard should be adopted for other things as well, as it more accurately reflects a 'growing' community than pure score does.

Answer (score 1):

In theory:

- If a tag is active there shouldn't be a lack of users qualified to vote on suggested synonyms.
- If a tag isn't active, then synonyms aren't necessary; questions with the would-be synonym tag can just be edited to use the correct tag.

In practice:

- This problem is usually dealt with by asking a moderator to do it here on meta.  See [retag-request](/questions/tagged/retag-request) and [synonym-request](/questions/tagged/synonym-request).
- [coronasdk](/questions/tagged/coronasdk) (the only currently proposed synonym for [corona](/questions/tagged/corona)) currently has 358 questions (compared to corona's 672) which is too many for convenient manual retagging.

**Suggestion: Just make a synonym request here on Meta.**
Then go vote up/bounty whichever of the various solutions to the system's defects looks best to you.  (Don't hold your breath though, this isn't a new problem.)

A selection of proposed remedies:

- [Scale requirement by number of questions in tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/69661/137004)
- [Allow sufficiently high-rep users to propose synonyms regardless of tag score](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/103211/137004)
- [George's proposal here to always allow the top N users in the tag to moderate it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168540/137004)

Comment: I already did this, and the fact that noone did anything about my attempt that inspired me to write about this issue...

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146064/make-the-corona-tag-synonym-of-coronasdk

Comment: @speeder Nice.  I'd recommend adding something about that to your question since it suggests that the current de facto system isn't working and makes the case for a change more pressing.